# asyncio.create_connection instaniates a ThreadPoolExecuter with each call

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

The tcp client code below basically loops until it is able to establish a connection with a tcp server.  When debugging in vs code I noticed that each call to create_connection() seems to create a new ThreadPoolExecutor instance.  This may pose a problem when my tcp server is not running because it seems as if an unlimited number of instances will be created.  What is the proper way to handle calling create_connection() many times when the server is not running?

[image]

```
async def do_tcp_connect(host, port, queue, shutdown_event, callbacks, connection_list):

    logger = logging.getLogger('do_tcp_connect')
    logger.debug('do_tcp_connect(): started')

    while True:
        try:
            transport, protocol = await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_connection(lambda: asyncio_callback(host, port, queue, shutdown_event, callbacks, connection_list), host, port)
            return
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except asyncio.CancelledError as ex:
            logger.error("network_queue_consumer(): CancelledError: A asyncio coroutine task was cancelled, error={}".format(ex))
        except AttributeError as ex:
            logger.error("network_queue_consumer(): AttributeError: An attribute reference or assignment has failed, error:{}".format(ex))
        except OSError as ex:
            logger.error("network_queue_consumer(): OSError error:{}".format(ex))
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error('network_queue_consumer(): Exception occurred, error={}'.format(ex))
        except:
            logger.error("network_queue_consumer(): Unexpected error: {}".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
            raise

        await asyncio.sleep(5.0)

    logger.debug('do_tcp_connect(): completed')
```

Comment: How have you concluded that each call to `create_connection` creates a new instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`? How did you obtain the attached screenshot?

Comment: @user4815162342 - When running with the debugger I had a breakpoint set at create_connection() and when I execute create_connection() another ThreadPoolExecutor is added.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the the asyncio source code and found that ThreadPoolExecutor was being instantiated in the method below.  Calling loop.set_default_executor(executor) seems to fix the issue I was having.

```
asyncio:base_events.py:742
    def run_in_executor(self, executor, func, *args):
        self._check_closed()
        if self._debug:
            self._check_callback(func, 'run_in_executor')
        if executor is None:
            executor = self._default_executor
            if executor is None:
                executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                self._default_executor = executor
        return futures.wrap_future(
            executor.submit(func, *args), loop=self)
```